# How to load components dynamically in Angular 2, without listing them in NgModule's declarations section

Tags: javascript, angular

We have an SPL, in which in `index.html` an ngModule is defined this way:

```
var module = ng.core.NgModule({
        imports: [ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule, ng.router.RouterModule, ng.material.MaterialModule],
        declarations: [],
        bootstrap: []
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function () {}
    });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    ng.platformBrowserDynamic
        .platformBrowserDynamic()
        .bootstrapModule(module);
});
```

As you can see the list of declarations in our `NgModule` is empty. This code is done by developer A for example, and is loaded into the page alongside `index.html`

In another place, developer B creates a simple component:

```
var tasks = ng.core.Component({
        selector: 'tasks',
        template: '<div>list of tasks here<div>'
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function () {}
    });
```

This code is loaded lazily, via user's interaction and route change.

How can we include this component in our module? The pseudo-code might be:

```
module.AddComponent(tasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using forwardRef but i'm not sure if it works sine i dont have any code to test with.

```
 var module = ng.core.NgModule({
            imports: [ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule, ng.router.RouterModule, ng.material.MaterialModule],
            declarations: [ng.core.forwardRef(() => tasks],
            bootstrap: []
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () { }
        });
```